# "He admitted that had he but taken my advice..."

Tags: conditional-constructions, inversion

Is the word **but** in the sentence below necessary here? Or is it just an intensifier?
What is the difference between them in terms of meaning?

> He admitted that had he **but** taken my advice, he would have saved
> himself money.( original)
>
> He admitted that had he  taken my advice, he would have saved
> himself money. ( I omitted the word 'but')

Answer (score 2):

The word **but** is not necessary in that sentence. It does have an intensifying nuance but really means "if **only** he had" or "if he had **just** take my advice..." My sense is that the sentence with **but** is slightly more literary than "if only he had" or "if he had just."